# Nette php framework does not run on xampp localhost

Tags: php, xampp, nette

I am completely new to [nette](https://doc.nette.org/en/quickstart/getting-started) php framework and I followed these steps to start my very first nette project:

1- `cd xampp/htdocs`

2- `composer create-project nette/web-project nette-blog`

3- opened up **`http://localhost/nette-blog`** & **`http://localhost/nette-blog/ww`**

But here I faced this error on browser:

> **Forbidden** You don't have permission to access this resource.

---

So what's going wrong here? How can I run nette project properly on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is in .htaccess file in nette-blog folder, where is command

```
Require all denied
```

Replace it by something like

```
#Require all denied

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www/$1 [L]
```